# Update and delete if fields match

Tags: php, mysql

I understand that it's a little rude to ask a question without any work to show, however I'm a little stumped and I need some help.

I need to delete a row from a mysql table if another field in another table is equal to 1

I have two tables `table_1` and `table_2`

`table_1` has two fields `location` and `events`

and `table_2` has a field called `location` which is the same as `location` on `table_1`

I would like to delete one or more rows from `table_2` if field `location` is the same as `table_1` and `events` = 1

something like:

```
if `events` = 1 in `table_1` in 'location' `*`;
    delete row(s) from `table_2`
    where `location` is the same as `location` in `table_1`
```

Comment: Make a SELECT (processing results) and then a DELETE query is too simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE t2
  FROM `table2` t2
  JOIN `table1` t1 ON t1.events = 1
                  AND t1.location = t2.location
```

Comment: t1 is killing me i understand the concept however t1.location is giving me an error as well. im asuming t1 and t2 are the fields.

Comment: @trey: no its alias for table1 and table2.

Comment: t1.location is getting interpreted as a column. ...#1054 - Unknown column 't1.location' in 'on clause'

Comment: You have `events` & `location` columns in `table1` and `location` column in `table2`, right? Otherwise, can you post your tables structure? And `t1`, `t2` are aliases for `table1`,  `table2`.

Comment: @trey: try this: `DELETE t2
  FROM table2 t2
  JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.location = t2.location
                  where t1.events=1`

Comment: problem corrected that was my internal mistake. :? CORRECT ANSWER! THANK YOU A BUNCH BRO. YOU SAVED ME A DAY. :D

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
delete from `table_2` 
   where location in (select location from `table_1` where events=1)
```

---

**Edit**

```
DELETE t2 FROM `table_2` t2 
   JOIN `table_1` t1 ON t1.location = t2.location where t1.events=1
```

Comment: phpmyadmin is not accepting this format bro. i tried several times

Comment: @trey: Don't know much in PHP. But does it give any error? This issue is related to PHP or my query?

Comment: its not accepting anything inside the brackets (select location from `table_1` where events=1)

Comment: i understand both of your concepts however the results are not working. i guess i have to bang my head against my laptop for another day or so. lol